# Retrofit: How to deal with server side returning errors?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I am having issues with dealing the server-side errors.

When I send my request, I expect to get a list of objects which looks like this:

```
{"Search":[{"some data"}, {"more data"}]}
```

But if the data is not found it returns:

```
{"Response":"False","Error":"Too many results."}
```

which crashes my app since its not a list. How do I solve this?

**Retrofit Interface**

```
interface Api {

    @GET("https://www.website.com/")
    fun getInformation(@Query("apikey") apiKey: String, @Query("p") name: String): Call<List>
}
```

**Repo**

```
 var list: MutableLiveData<List<Object>> = MutableLiveData()
 val call: Call<ObjectList> = ObjectApi.getObjectInformation(API_KEY, objectSearch)
        call.enqueue(object: Callback<ObjectList>{
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ObjectList>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("TEST", "Error: ${t.message}")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ObjectList>, response: Response<ObjectList>) {
                Log.d("TEST", "Success: ${response.body()}")
                val _list = response.body()
                list.value = _list.objects
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to handle the error response in `onResponse` as well with success call.

Note that according to [documents](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-callback/on-response/)

```
Note that transport-layer success (receiving a HTTP response code, headers and body) does not necessarily indicate application-layer success: response may still indicate an unhappy HTTP response code like 404 or 500.
```

That means you need to handle the http status code inside `onResponse`

May be you can send 404 if there is no result and handle the response as below

```
when(response.code) {
  200 -> // call response.body() and deserialize to object
  404 -> // you can use errorBody and thow exception or handle the error
  else -> // handle other error codes
}
```

[errorBody](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Response.html#errorBody--)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which language you are using for your API's, but some of the languages only use Arrays. I'm guessing your Response object is `ObjectList`. Can you send the code for the Response object class as well?

Comment: Yeah, I am writing in Kotlin. my ObjectList is just a model class that holds the data that is supposed to be coming in. It just has fields.

Comment: By language I meant the language you meant to write the API's themselves, not the language for your Android project. Is it fine if you could send the code for the ObjectList class?